# Working with AngularJS and Websql phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, web-sql

I am creating a Phonegap app (Android and iOS) using AngularJS and Websql.
My problem is that i am finding it difficult getting from the Websql query into controller/view.

This is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="inmoment">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/catMenu.js"></script>
  <script src="js/models.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<ul ng-controller="sampleController">
 <li ng-repeat="cat in cats">
   {{cat.catID}}<br />
   {{cat.Title}}<br />
   {{cat.cCount}}<br />
   {{cat.mCount}}
 </li>
</ul>

<script src="js/my-app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller Script

```
var inmomentNameSpace = angular.module('inmoment', []);
inmomentNameSpace.controller('sampleController', function sampleController(
    $scope) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        $("#catList").empty();
        tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT CATEGORY.catID, CATEGORY.Title, CATEGORY.image, COUNT(SUBCATEGORY.subID) as cCount, COUNT(MESSAGETB.mesID) as mCount, SUBCATEGORY.title, SUBCATEGORY.catID FROM CATEGORY LEFT OUTER JOIN SUBCATEGORY ON CATEGORY.catID = SUBCATEGORY.catID LEFT OUTER JOIN MESSAGETB ON SUBCATEGORY.subID = MESSAGETB.subID GROUP BY CATEGORY.catID ORDER BY CATEGORY.Title ASC', [],
            function(tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length;
                var catObj = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    catObj[i] = results.rows.item(i);
                }
                console.log(catObj);
                $scope.cats = catObj;
            })
    })
})
```

When I console.log(catObj), I get the results alright, but they seem not work with my controller.
I will be glad if anyone can help me. Thank you

Comment: try $timeout(function(){$scope.cats = catObj;}) btw you should inject $timeout in the controller. Inside transaction you are out of the angular real so you shoul use $timeout or $apply

Comment: Thank you @Whisher, Please can you elaborate your answer a bit with sample code since I am newbie and couldn't find where to place the $timeout(function(){$scope.cats = catObj;}) and $timeout. Thank you

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/whisher/e2d6fe7f9140bb3945f5

Comment: @Whisher, It worked. Thank you. Can you make it an answer for me to mark it for you and those who are interested in it.